# GLTF model is too dark

Tags: three.js

Trying to load this model of a car into my scene, here is how it looks in the glTF Viewer:

[image]

I followed that example. With this updated loading method, the model is still dark, and if I try to scale or position it, it completely disappears.

Here is how it's loaded:

```
 const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
const roughnessMipmapper = new RoughnessMipmapper( renderer );
loader.load( 'models/car_datsun/scene.gltf', function ( gltf ) { 
    gltf.scene.traverse( function (child) {
        if (child.isMesh) {
            roughnessMipmapper.generateMipmaps(child.material);
        }
        child.scale.set(0.5,0.5,0.5); //must comment this line out to appear 
        child.position.y += 10; //must comment this line out to appear
        child.position.z += 20; //must comment this line out to appear
    });
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
}, undefined, function ( error ) {
    console.error(error);
});
roughnessMipmapper.dispose();
```

I also have a light, which is meant to simulate the sun:

```
 const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
 light.position.set(500,200,500); //looking at 0,0,0
 scene.add(light);
```

Renderer is set to use sRGB:

```
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
```

Comment: Can you try to add an environment map to the material (similar to this example https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_gltf)? It has probably a high metalness value and thus won't reflect the directional light as you would expect.

Comment: @Mugen87 i updated the loading method to be like the example, but it's still dark. Also, now I can't scale or position the model, as that makes it disappear.

Comment: Please share your code as a live example or a git repository so it's to investigate this issue.